# Flask send_file returns empty csv file

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am creating simple flask application where user inputs the excel file using /upload function in one route and processing pandas operations on same route and it has to return processed data frame to csv/excel in /download route. so far i used this code

```
@application.route('/chart1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            global dfw
            df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'), skiprows=13, sep=";", header=None)
            df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
            df.replace(['0x', ''], ['', ''], regex=True, inplace=True)
            df.columns = ["Time", "Type", "ID", "DL", "D0", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6"]
            session["df"] = df.to_csv(index=False, header=True, sep=";")
            return render_template('upload.html')
@application.route("/download", methods=["POST"])
def download():
    csv = session["df"] if "df" in session else ""
    buf_str = io.StringIO(csv)
    buf_byt = io.BytesIO(buf_str.read().encode("utf-8"))
    return send_file(buf_byt,
                     mimetype="text/csv",
                     as_attachment=True,
                     download_name="data.csv")
```

the above code returning empty data.csv file how to correct it

Comment: Why do you need to have two separate routes? Why not just have the `/chart1` route respond with the result? You can't store a Pandas dataframe in the session data.

Comment: For download button iam creating another route can we do it with same route how can I do it